# Transparent color between ToggleButton and Popup

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a tooglebutton, the IsChecked action is to open a popup.

I want to put a margin between these controls that need to be transparent.
Like in the red area :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/37DXQ.jpg

In reality, I have :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9edg.jpg

My code in xaml :

```
<Popup x:Name="ToggledPopup" StaysOpen="True" IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=TogglePopupButton, Mode=TwoWay}"
                   Closed="ToggledPopup_OnClosed"
                   PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=TogglePopupButton}"
                   Placement="Bottom" PopupAnimation="Slide">

<Border Height="250" Width="360" Background="White" Margin="0,20,0,0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">

<dashboard:NotifierDetailsView/>
</Border></Popup>
```

Could you help me in my issue ?

Regards

Comment: If I understand you problem well then try with `<Popup ... AllowTransparency="True">`

Comment: I use <HorizontalOffset="-290" VerticalOffset="6> in the popup control to put the right position

Comment: To me looks like a rendering error. There never should be a black area inside your window, and I guess you haven't set a UIElements Color explicitely to black. could you post the visual parents of the popup. It would be interesting to reproduce

Answer (score 0):

The parent control of the popup is this one:

> ToggleButton x:Name="TogglePopupButton"
>   Background="{Binding WarningCount, Converter={StaticResourceCountToBackground}, ConverterParameter='0'}">
>
> ```
>        <Label HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
>               HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
>               VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
>
>            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
>                <Grid Width="15" Height="15">
>                    <Path Data="{StaticResource WarningsFlagGeometry}" 
>                          Fill="{Binding WarningCount, Converter={StaticResource CountToForeground}, ConverterParameter='0'}"
>                          Stretch="Uniform"/>
>                </Grid>
>
>                <Label Name="Label" 
>                       FontWeight="Bold" 
>                       Content="{Binding WarningCount}"
>                       Foreground="{Binding WarningCount, Converter={StaticResource CountToForeground}, ConverterParameter='0'}"
>                       Margin="4,0,0,0" />
>            </StackPanel>
>        </Label>
>    </ToggleButton>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In the context of positioning the Popup "Bottom", zero out the (top) Margin:

```
<Border Height="250" Width="360" Background="White" Margin="0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black"
```